# pixel.getGreen vs pixel.getGreen()

Tags: javascript, pixel

I'm working on an assignment that uses `pixel.getGreen()` method. My question is when I try using `pixel.getGreen` (without the parentheses) I get a different result than when using the method with parentheses. What's the difference between the two?
Here's the code I'm working with:

```
function swapRedGreen(pixel){ 
    var oldRed = pixel.getRed();
    var oldGreen = pixel.getGreen();
    pixel.setRed(oldGreen); 
    pixel.setGreen(oldRed); 
    return pixel;
}
var image = new SimpleImage("smallhands.png");
print (image);
for (var pixel of image.values()) { 
        pixel = swapRedGreen(pixel); 
    } 
print (image);
```

I get a pitch black image when I try running the code without the parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pixel.getGreen()` is a function *invocation*, whereas `pixel.getGreen` is just accessing the `getGreen` property of the `pixel` object, which in this case, should be a function definition. Remember, you can reference a function without invoking it, but the parentheses in JS mean you are calling/invoking the function. Without seeing the library/source you're working with, it should be something like this:

```
var pixel = {
   getGreen: function() {
     return 'green';
   }
};
console.log(pixel.getGreen) // function() {...}
console.log(pixel.getGreen()) // 'green'
```

If that's *not* what you see, post some more context.

Comment: I have one question: I don't declare a function when using `pixel.getGreen` like in the example I've posted above. How does  the function work without declaring it first?

Comment: It looks like you're using a library. Is that right? If so, then the `getGreen` function is declared elsewhere, and when you type `var image = new SimpleImage("smallhands.png");` you have that function available to the `image` object via prototypal inheritance. If you don't know how prototypal inheritance works, definitely google it. It's worth understanding and is a very fundamental concept in javascript. Hope that helps!